# Styling placeholder-text with emotion js

Tags: javascript, html, css, emotion

Currently, `placeholder="Your best email"` is not being styled by style:`inputText`.

On inspecting element, the `user agent stylesheet` is being used for `input, textarea, select, button {}`.

Below is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import {css} from "@emotion/core";

const inputText = css`
  ::placeholder {
    float: left;
    height: 35px;
    width: 230px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: "Work Sans";
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 35px;
  }
`

const inputRound = css`
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 85px;
  width: 460px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 5px solid #FFF;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
`

const Subscribe = () => (
   <div css={{
     display: 'flex'
   }}>
      <h2>Stay tuned</h2>
      <form name="subscribe" method="POST" data-netlify="true">
        <p css={inputText}>
          <input placeholder="Your best email" type="email" name="email" css={inputRound}/>
        </p>
        <p >
          <button type="submit"><h3>Subscribe</h3></button>
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
)

export default Subscribe
```

What is preventing `inputText` style from being applied?

Here is a screenshot from dev tools (PS `inputText` has been altered to `& > ::placeholder` as suggested.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply the `inputText` style directly to the input:

```
// Change this
- <p css={inputText}>
-   <input css={inputRound}/>
- </p>

//to this
+ <p>
+   <input css={[inputText, inputRound]}/>
+ </p>
```

---

Or, alternatively, target child input from the `inputText`:

```
const inputText = css`
  & > input::placeholder {
    ...
  }
`
```

Comment: Thanks Derek, but unfortunately neither option is working! I've attached a screen shot from dev tools - what do you think could be happening?

Comment: Hi @isaacsultan, I read in your update that you’re using `& > ::placeholder`? It should be `& > input::placeholder {...}`. Let me know if that still doesn’t work!

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. Changed to `& > input::placeholder {...}` but still not working for me!

Comment: @isaacsultan working fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/5yjymkpkzn?fontsize=14 I have to remove the `float` rules for the placeholder to be visible, but the css does get applied even if I don't

Comment: Thank you so much, all sorted now!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to style the placeholder for the input, you can do it like this (this code is just for example):

```
input: css`
      width: 100px
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      border-radius: 3px;

      &::placeholder {
        color: red;
      }
    `,
```